# LLVM 3.4 performance regressed?

Tags: llvm, llvm-3.0

I use the [Spec 2006](http://www.spec.org/cpu2006/) benchmarks to measure the performance of a few private passes and the generated code. So far, all my work was based on [LLVM 3.1](http://llvm.org/releases/3.1/docs/ReleaseNotes.html).

Last week I wanted to move forward with LLVM, and I rebased all of my passes to [LLVM 3.4](http://llvm.org/releases/3.4/docs/ReleaseNotes.html). This required only adjusting a few `#include` lines. However, after that change I measured a huge performance regression. Next I disabled all of my custom passes, but still performance was down. Here are the numbers of a few Spec benchmarks compiled with LLVM 3.1 and 3.4

```
            LLVM 3.1  LLVM 3.4
            --------  --------
401.bzip2       7.50     17.5
429.mcf         4.72      8.10
456.hmmer       4.18     10.1
458.sjeng       4.85      8.86
433.milc       13.4      26.0
470.lbm        13.4      12.6
```

I also noticed that the number of functions called by e.g. `456.hmmer` went from 6 to 45009; similar numbers show for most other benchmarks. Inlining failed?

I compile the Spec benchmarks with

```
CC=clang -g -std=c89 -D_GNU_SOURCE -c -emit-llvm
```

and then call `opt` with

```
opt -simplifycfg -mem2reg -break-constgeps <my-passes> benchmark.bc -o benchmark.schnufte.bc
```

Once `opt` is done, the bitcode is lowered with `llc` and linked into an executable.

The performance regression is very noticable, and I doubt that 3.4 would have been released with a regression as obvious as that. So my question is: did I miss something? Are optimizations now invoked more explicitly? I added `-std-compile-opts` to my opt call after my passes, but that didn't help at all.

**EDIT** As suggested, I posed the question to the [LLVMdev mailing list](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/llvmdev/2014-April/071906.html), but the thread receives little attention.

Comment: I think both gcc and llvm are more interested in features than performance, I think both have been regressing slowly for a while.  not major but slow.  now that you point this out I may have to try 3.4 to see if I see something as dramatic as you are seeing.

Comment: You should post this question on the mailing lists.

Comment: Have you tried just running `opt -std-compile-opts`, without specifying your own pass list or providing custom passes, then comparing?

Comment: @Oak: Yes, and it had no effect.

Comment: Have you tried to use `-O3` et al.? Otherwise your benchmarking is kind of pointless, because the compiler doesn't even try to pruduce fast executables.